# Memory Monitoring Tool for Unity Applications on Android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, monitoring, memory-consumption

I am currently developing a memory intensive application in Unity3D.
Now I want to know, how much memory the applications needs at certain times and actions.

I know the memory monitoring tool in AndroidStudio, but it seems, that it doesn't really correlate with my observations of the memory consumption of the application itself.

Is there a good way to monitor the memory consumption of an Unity3D App deployed on an Android phone?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use built-it Profiler tool, it's pretty accurate and with graphs you should easily find memory/cpu spikes.

Also, Unity gives you this: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Profiler.GetRuntimeMemorySize.html

Very nice way to measure resources usage by selected objects.

Furthermore, you can use `PerformanceCounter`, but you have to include the complete .NET 2.0 libraries (not the subset).

```
System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter ramCounter = new PerformanceCounter("Memory", "Available MBytes");
Debug.Log(ramCounter.NextValue()+"MB");
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But doesn't the profiler only work, when I start the application in the Editor? But I want to measure the memory usage directly on the phone (The app doesn't work in the editor).

Alright thank you, I'll have a look at them.

Comment: Okay first it didn't work with the profiler, but now it works, I don't know why. Thank you!